# All NSTimers running after a previous timer that has been invalidated cease execution instead of continuing to run

Tags: ios, swift, nstimer

In my implementation I am running multiple timers at once on a UITableView and when one timer finishes, I invalidate it and allow it to be removed from said view. Currently the problem I am running into is that when one timer is removed, all others after it cease execution.

```
public class TimerManager{
    static let instance = TimerManager()
    private var delegates = [TimerDelegate]()
    var currentTimers = [TimerObject]()

    public func timerAdded(timer: TimerObject){
        self.currentTimers.append(timer)
        timer.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(persistTimer(_:)), userInfo: "\(TimerManager.instance.currentTimers.count-1)", repeats: false)
        timer.isRunning = true
        for delegate in delegates{
            delegate.startTimer(self.currentTimers[self.currentTimers.count-1])
        }
    }

    @objc public func persistTimer(timer: NSTimer){
        if let indexString = timer.userInfo as? String{
            if let index = Int(indexString){
                if let currentTimer = self.currentTimers[safe: index]{
                    if currentTimer.isRunning{
                        currentTimer.timeDuration -= 1
                        for delegate in delegates{
                            delegate.timerStarted(index)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public func addTime(timerId: Int, amount: Int){
        for delegate in delegates{
            delegate.addTimeToTimer(timerId, amount: amount)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(currentTimers[timerId].notification)
            currentTimers[timerId].notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: Double(currentTimers[timerId].timeDuration))
        }
    }

    public func subtractTime(timerId: Int, amount: Int){
        for delegate in delegates{
            delegate.subtractTimeFromTimer(timerId, amount: amount)
            UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(currentTimers[timerId].notification)
            currentTimers[timerId].notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: Double(currentTimers[timerId].timeDuration))
        }
    }

    public func removeDelegate(removedDelegate: TimerDelegate){
        for i in 0..<delegates.count{
            if delegates[i] === removedDelegate{
                delegates.removeAtIndex(i)
            }
        }
    }

    public func cancelTimer(timerId: Int){
        let currentTimer = currentTimers[timerId]
        currentTimer.timer.invalidate()
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(currentTimer.notification)
        currentTimers.removeAtIndex(timerId)
    }

    private init() {}
}
```

That is my TimerManager singleton above.
Below is my delete logic:

```
//Delete cell functionality
    public override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if( editingStyle == .Delete){
            let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
            let screenWidth = screenSize.width
            let screenHeight = screenSize.height
            let deletedTimer = TimerManager.instance.currentTimers[indexPath.row]
            if (deletedTimer.isRunning){
                deletedTimer.timer.invalidate()// <-- invalidates all timers for some reason
                UIApplication.sharedApplication().cancelLocalNotification(deletedTimer.notification)
            }
            TimerManager.instance.currentTimers.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
            self.tableView.frame = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 100, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight * 0.0625 * CGFloat(TimerManager.instance.currentTimers.count))
        }
    }
```

This is how I start a timer:

```
public func startTimer(timer: TimerObject) {
        let newIndexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: TimerManager.instance.currentTimers.count-1, inSection: 0)
        self.tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([newIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height
        self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 100, screenWidth, screenHeight * 0.0625 * CGFloat(TimerManager.instance.currentTimers.count))
        self.view.alpha = 0.95

    }
```

This is what my TimerObject consists of:

```
public class TimerObject{
    var alreadySet = false
    var isRunning = false
    var timer = NSTimer()
    var timeDuration = Int()
    var timerString = String()
    var doneString = String()
    let notification = UILocalNotification()

    init(timeDuration: Int, timerString: String, doneString: String){
        self.timeDuration = timeDuration
        self.timerString = timerString
        self.doneString = doneString
        notification.alertBody = doneString
    }
}
```

Instantiation of a TimerObject:

```
private func setTextLinks(string: String){
        if let timersForInstruction = parsedOutTimers{
            stepTextView.linkTextAttributes = [NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.redColor()]
            for timer in timersForInstruction{
                stepTextView.addLink(string.substringFromRange(timer.range)) {
                    let newTimer = TimerObject.init(timeDuration: timer.lowerBound * 60, timerString: self.stepTitle
                    newTimer.notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: Double(newTimer.timeDuration))
                    TimerManager.instance.timerAdded(newTimer)
                }
            }
            stepTextView.processLinks()
        }
    }
```

I would say this is where it is used:

```
//where we update the cells
    public func timerIsRunning(timerIndex: Int){
        if let currentTimer = TimerManager.instance.currentTimers[safe: timerIndex]{
            guard let cell = self.tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath.init(
                forRow: timerIndex,
                inSection: 0)) as? TimerCell else { return }
            if currentTimer.timeDuration > 0{
                currentTimer.timeDuration -= 1
                cell.timerDisplay.text = "\(currentTimer.timerString) \t\t\t - \(currentTimer.timeDuration / 60):\((currentTimer.timeDuration % 60).format("02")) + "
                cell.timerDisplay.processLinks()
            }else if(currentTimer.timeDuration <= 0){
                currentTimer.isRunning = false
                cell.timerDisplay.text = "Finished"
                currentTimer.timer.invalidate()
                currentTimer.notification.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 0)
                currentTimer.notification.alertBody = currentTimer.doneString
                currentTimer.notification.alertAction = "Ok"
                if(self.isBeingPresented()){
                    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("timerDidFinish", object: currentTimer.notification.alertBody)
                }
                if(UIApplicationState.Background == UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState){
                    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(currentTimer.notification)
                }
            }else{
                //handle pause 
            }
        }

    }
```

I sincerely hope this is enough information to work with. 
Any solutions or alternatives would help greatly.

Comment: Never do `var timer = NSTimer()`. You show no example of creating and using a `TimerObject`. Your question is better than yesterday, but you should really explain both how you use this class and what your actual user goal is - why do you have lots of timers anyway, why not 1 timer and objects which hold a 'fires till expired' or simply an NSDate when they expire?

Comment: Sorry, I am unsure of how show the usage of timer object without a screenshot of the application. I will explain as best as I can. The user clicks on a link that is mapped to an action which notifies the singleton to start a timer for X amount of minutes, the start timer function then creates a new cell in the tableview displaying the running timer. I use an NSTimer to notify persistTimer to tell the tableView to update the cell with the newly decremented time. The user can start any number of timers and they can activate a timer any amount of times, these are the constraints.

Comment: Using an NSDate would not allow me to update the tableView every second. Also, can you please go into more detail as to why `var timer = NSTimer()` is taboo?

Comment: what do you mean `activate a timer any amount of times`? and I mean show code of you creating an instance of `TimerObject` and using it

Comment: @Eric D - I was curious about your response relative to creating a lot of timers, so I went and read the link again thoroughly, but I missed anything that talked about why many of them would be a bad thing. I don't agree with how he has built this, but I was curious on that technical point. What's your thinking?

Comment: @Eric D - Thank you for taking the time to post the link, reading through helped me get more familiar with the NSRunLoop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix my own problem by instead instantiating a new timer for each object, there's just one timer that's updating the view for all objects.

```
private var timer = NSTimer()
    var isFirstTimer = false


    public func timerAdded(newTimerObject: TimerObject){
        if(isFirstTimer){
            self.timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1.0, target: self, selector: #selector(persistTimers(_:)), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }
        self.currentTimers.append(newTimerObject)
        newTimerObject.isRunning = true
        for delegate in delegates{
            delegate.startTimer(self.currentTimers[self.currentTimers.count-1])
        }
    }

    @objc public func persistTimers(timer: NSTimer){
        for i in 0..<self.currentTimers.count{
            if let currentTimer = currentTimers[safe: i]{
                if(currentTimer.isRunning){
                    currentTimer.timeDuration -= 1
                    for delegate in delegates{
                        delegate.timerStarted(i)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is ultimately what I ended up changing in my singleton declaration and 
I ended up removing the

```
currentTimer.timeDuration -= 1
```

line from the timerStarted function into the persistTime function... I realize my implementation and style have a lot to be desired but it's a start. Only 2 weeks into iOS programming after all.

EDIT:

the `"[safe: ]"` extension I added is for safe index access:

```
public extension CollectionType{
    subscript (safe index: Index) -> Generator.Element? {
        return indices.contains(index) ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```